# chrome.downloads.download gives "Error during downloads.download: Invalid URL."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I am making an extension for Google Chrome which uses the Downloads API.
I want to download a .jpg file from a website.

I have used these permissions in the manifest:

```
"permissions": ["downloads", "*://www.thatsite.com/*"]
```

and the command i am using is:

```
chrome.downloads.download({"url":"https://www.thatsite.com/images/image1.jpg"});
```

This gives the following error

> "Error during downloads.download: Invalid URL."

Any ideas how to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with following code, and it is working as expected. I hope you are **not on** Stable Channel.

Put your complete code, the problem is entirely with URL.

You can refer following code as a reference

## Reference

#### manifest.json

Registered **browser action** and **permissions** with manifest file.

```
{
    "name": "Download Demo",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560465/chrome-downloads-download-gives-error-during-downloads-download-invalid-url",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads",
        "*://www.google.co.in/*"
    ]
}
```

#### popup.html

Added `<script>` file to comply with **CSP**.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="download">Download</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### popup.js

Simply passed **URL** to `download API`.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function () {
        chrome.downloads.download({
            "url": "http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
        }, function () {
            console.log("downloaded");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is correct. There was a slight error in my manifest file. The image was on the website but hosted on a different site and i hadn't written that in permissions. Thanks.

Comment: @Sudarshan how can we do the same thing if we are in a stable channel ?

Comment: @ShikharSharma Must we set the permission in manifest.xml to allow api to download from that site?